# не могу запустить тестовую страничку на nginx

Tags: nginx

OC Windows. Создал простой файл index.html, положил его в папку сервера nginx data/www
Беру настройки сервера из примера документации [nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html)

```
server {
    location / {
        root data/www;
    }
}
```

Все остальные секции server закомментировал. Запускаю Nginx.
Ввожу адрес в браузере

```
http://localhost
или так http://localhost/index.html
```

и вместо моей страницы открывается "Welcome to nginx!" Я же все закомментил в настройках. Что я делаю не так?
Текст очень большой, поэтому кидаю ссылку:
[nginx -T](https://pastein.ru/t/tQ2)

Вот обновленный конфиг

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    server {
        #listen       81;
        #server_name example.ru;
        
        location / {
            root data/www;
            #root C:\Development\nginx\data\www;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно у меня какая-то неизведанная проблема с localhost. Но как мне задать свое имя. Пробую прописать, в вопросе он закомментирован

```
server_name example.ru
```

Но ни по одному из запрос также не открывается эта страница

```
http://example.ru
example.ru
example.ru:81
```

Comment: В документации не такой пример. И вообще он для *nix. В винде, наверное, надо бы в путь добавить букву диска. Ну и, а вы nginx перезапустили?

Comment: Почему не такой, убрал ту часть где картинку добавили. Пробовал указывать и полный путь "root C:\Development\nginx\data\www;". nginx  -s reload делал

Comment: Лучше restart. И покажите вывод `nginx -T`

Comment: добавил в вопрос, а "nginx -s restart" пишет, что такой команды нет

Comment: Остановите и запустите сервис заново. Я не знаю как это делается в винде, но это наверняка можно сделать. Как минимум путём перезагрузки компьютера =0

Comment: Сделал, не помогло. Мне кажется где-то прописана конфигурация по умолчанию или что-то еще.

Answer (score 0):

1. Уберите из конфига абсолютный путь, если Ваши файлы лежат в папке сервера, так как:

> nginx/Windows использует каталог, в котором он был запущен, в качестве префикса для относительных путей в конфигурации.

2. Поменяйте слеши c "\" на "/" так как:

> Пути в конфигурационном файле должны задаваться в UNIX-стиле с использованием прямых слэшей:

3. Сохраните и сделайте

   nginx -s reload

P.S. Старица "Welcome" дефолтно находится в папке html в Windows версии, nginx кидает Вас туда. Вы не делали донастройку сервера? Не прописывали site-enabled и site-available?

Comment: нет, ни чего дополнительного не делал, установил nginx, открыл документацию и пробую. Абсолютный путь я добавил по просьбе  Alexey Ten. До этого был относительный, см. текст вопроса

Comment: Я сделал все с Вашими путями и конфигом и всё завелось с 1 раза. Тут на самом деле такое. Воспроизвести Вашу проблему удалось только путем раскомментирования блока server с root html. Может быть стоит попробовать удалить конфиг файл и создать новый пустой с нужными параметрами.

Comment: изменил конфиг, добавил в вопрос, у меня ни чего не поменялось, так же перехожу на "Welcome", а не на свою

Comment: Уберите "/" перед data, и когда сохраните файл и сделаете nginx -s reload, попробуйте запустить localhost в режиме инкогнито, чтобы кеш не подгружался. У Вас же html и заголовки modified не настроены, он весь кешируется.

Comment: Исправил, запустил в привате, все равно Welcome. Хочу попробовать другой путь, не localhost. Как мне сделать чтобы запускать по этой строке "server_name example.ru;" Что-то еще надо где-то прописывать?