# Выбор веб-сервера под виндовс

Tags: веб-сервер

Мне нужно написать небольшую вебку и соединить ее серверным приложением (backend). Все будет крутиться на локальной машине в местной сети. Буквально 4-5 будут иметь доступ к этому приложению. Пока что все будет под Windows, в дальнейшем планируется развитие приложения и переход ни Linux.
C Frontend ни когда дел не имел, поэтому без разницы было, что изучать и решил использовать Angular. Написал тестовый пример.

Теперь встал вопрос на каком web-сервере все это запустить. Google сказал, что щас рулит nginx. И ни чего не вышло ни с Angular, даже обычную html страничку не смог разместить на сервере, по примеру из документации на сервер.
На stackoverflow мне сказали, что nginx заточен под nix системы, возможно с этим связаны эти проблемы.

Подскажите какой мне лучше взять web-сервер для своей задачи, основные требования он должен быть бесплатный, заточен под винду и простой в освоении для новичка, ну и желательно с хорошей документацией и главное, чтобы было описание как развернуть на нем Angular приложение (как я понял с каждым сервером у Angular есть свои особенности). А если сервер стабильно может работать и под виндой и под Linux, то это просто самый лучший вариант.

Comment: nginx - хорошее решение. А что именно не получилось настроит? может проще взять докер и там все сразу стартануть (хотя это будет сильно дольше настривать). Angular  - это клиентская система и в принципе ей побоку, кто там на сервере, главное, что бы файлики отдавал.

Comment: вот мой вопрос по nginx, я не могу даже с localhost разобраться, пробую прописать свое имя, тоже не выходит ни чего
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275463/не-могу-запустить-тестовую-страничку-на-nginx/1275492?noredirect=1#comment2246418_1275492

Comment: Наверно, это будет немного странно, но может попробовать http://www.denwer.ru/ или его аналоги? там как минимум куча дружественной документации

Comment: а почему странно?

Comment: Потому что на дворе 2021 год, докеры и все такое

Comment: т.е. если откинуть докер, то denwer будет нормальным решением? На сколько я понимаю докер это больше для продакшена. А я не собираюсь ни чего распространять, этот сайт будет установлен локально на одном компе и навсегда, пока он не накроется

Comment: докер как раз сделан, что бы переносить с локальной машины а продакшн было не больно. Потому что разработчики также делают все докере, а дальше автоматизация.
Пробуйте денвер, возможно, для Вас это самое простое решение. Хотя если оно будет на одной машине и под виндой, то может классический IIS?